# font awesome ios icons all the same

Tags: ios, font-awesome

I'm trying to use FontAwesome on my ios app (ios8, xcode6), and am having trouble.  I've downloaded the font, tried the TTF and OTF versions separately. I've included the font name in my plist file, and have included the NSString+FontAwesome and UIFont+FontAwesome categories that are standard out there.

The problem is that every font awesome symbol showing is always this same one.  Everything works, it just never changes the character.

```
id github  = [NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FAGithub];
id twitter = [NSString fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:FATwitter];

label1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontAwesomeFamilyName size:32.f];
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", github, twitter];
```

[image]

If I use the unicode string directly instead of the helpers, it is still always the same

```
@"\uf001"
@"\uf002"
// etc
```

When I debugged the category classes and printed out the unicode array with all the font-awesome codes in the console, all the symbols were identical to the ones above.

```
[NSString fontAwesomeUnicodeStrings]
```

**Has anyone seen this problem of the repeating symbol, or know a resolution?**

[image]

**EDIT**

2 weeks later, after fixing by re-install:  I believe the symbol shown is, which was always the same, is the result of the label's font either not being set correctly to FontAwesome, or the font not being loaded so it is not able to be set.  That is the symbol that shows up when font is set to something like "System".

Comment: I've been using https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit since it has a pod install option, but from https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome says that you need to use the `UIAppFonts` key in the plist, and their types are explicitly set to `NSString` when calling `fontAwesomeIconStringForEnum:`.. dont know if it will matter, but worth a shot

Comment: UIAppFonts key maps to the same thing I used, "Fonts provided by application".  I tried the NSString explicit typing too, no difference.  Thanks for the ideas tho.

Comment: ah good to know, thanks! You got me curious so I tried implementing it myself, and it worked with both what the readme suggested and with your code. I also tried playing around with some stuff (compile sources, linked libraries, etc.) to see if I could replicate your issue, but couldn't. Not sure where the problem lies, but I could upload the project to git if it would help to compare

Comment: i have nothing better to do, so https://github.com/spacedrabbit/StackScratchPad

Comment: I tested your github project, it worked as you said.   Instead of comparing my setup line-per-line, I deleted my installed categories, the font, and followed your lead of adding the ios-fontawesome github directly in my project.  I unreferenced the non-ios items in xcode to keep it clean.  I compiled and my existing references to font-awesome worked.  It doesn't answer why it didn't previously, but it did fix the problem.   If you want credit for the solution add an "Answer" below, with very brief desc of this.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps taken for this to work:

1. File > Add File > Added ios-fontawesome in it entirety (copied folder)
2. Removed all .m files from fontawesome besides NSString+FontAwesome.m from compile sources
3. Added FontAwesome.tff to info.plist key Fonts Provided By Application

(Compiled for iPhone 5s Sim, 8.1 using XCode 6.1.1)

Test project listed here: https://github.com/spacedrabbit/StackScratchPad

As the comments indicate, this doesn't explain why it wasn't working it just is the way I was able to make it work.